# How to change variance-covariance matrix in mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix, statistical-power

I'm currently trying to do power calculation using **SIMR** package in R.
To start off, I first created the following model which defines my study design with simulated output y:

```
model1 <- glmer(y ~ (a*b) +
                        (1 + (a*b)|subj), family="binomial",
                        data = simulated.df, 
                        control = glmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+9)))
```

I would now like to adjust the variance-covariance matrix of this model based on my pilot data. The varcorr matrix of my pilot data is as follows:

```
#> VarCorr(m_pilot)
  #Groups   Name             Std.Dev. Corr                
  #subj     (Intercept)      0.11582                      
  #a1                        0.12624  -0.254              
  #b1                        0.12239  -0.080  0.563       
  #a1:b1                     0.10523   0.267 -0.600 -0.337
```

How can I change the varcorr matrix of my stimulated model (model1) to the varcor matrix from my pilot data?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Maria

Comment: R code questions might be better received on the r-sig-mixed-models mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy the variance-covariance matrix from one model to the other with:

```
VarCorr(model1) <- VarCorr(m_pilot)
```